# Laravel create a route method GET with param in url

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

I created a route & contronller:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function () {
        Route::get('product/{id}', ['uses' => 'ProductController@getProduct']);
});
```

ProductController:

```
class ProductController extends MyController {

public $_params = null;
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->_params = $request->all();
    $options = array();
    parent::__construct($options);
}

public function getProduct() {
    dd($this->_params);
}
}
```

I requested: http://localhost/test/product/123

But the id = 123 not exist in $this->_params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests) params are input data like POST data. To access route params you will need to make another class property like "$routeParams"

```
class ProductController extends MyController {

    public $_params = null;
    public $routeParams = null;
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_params = $request->all();
        $this->routeParams = $request->route()->parameters();
        $options = array();
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function getProduct() {
        dd($this->routeParams);
    }
}
```

---

I understand need to implement your logic on top of the Laravel, but I would suggest that you do that in some Services, Actions, Domain.... Maybe this can help: https://laravel-news.com/controller-refactor

You can try do it like [basic controller from documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#basic-controllers)
and make some custom service for complex stuff.

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        $productService = new ProductService($id);
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of the route parameters, you need to use `$request->route()->parameters()`, not `$request->all()`

`$request->all()` returns the query parameters for GET requests

Answer (score 0):

$request->all() only get parameter from header, body and URL but can't get parameter from route product/{id}

You should replace func getProduct to param id
`public function getProduct($id) { dd($id); }`

Comment: i use $request->route()->parameters(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

İf you want all params in request use $request->all() method but you want only id in url $request->id

Comment: $request->all() not work. i use $request->route()->parameters()

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't write all of my comment